# Плагин для рефакторинга для Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, поиск-программ, visual-studio-2019

Подскажите, есть ли для `Visual Studio` какой-нибудь мощный и бесплатный плагин, который добавляет новые варианты рефакторингов?

Как я понимаю, стандартными инструментами `Visual Studio` можно только методы извлекать и выполнять переименования, в то время, как `ReSharper` умеет параметры местами менять, извлекать классы и т д...

Comment: возможно вы ищите какие-то определенные возможности среды? если да, то напишите что вас интересует.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Сделать анонимную функцию именованной, поменять порядок параметров в методе, удалить параметр из метода и всех местах, где он используется.

Answer (score 3):

1. есть `ReSharper` - очень мощный и многофункциональный плагин, нацеленный в большей степени на повышение производительности разработчика: автозаполнения,оптимизация  и генерация кода и прочее
2. второе, что мне приходилось использовать - `PVS-Studio` - статический анализатор кода, инструмент для выявления ошибок и потенциальных уязвимостей в исходном коде программ
3. также можете посмотреть на `Visual Assist`, являющийся чем-то похожим на `ReSharper` по предоставляемому функционалу

Именно для рефакторинга и только я бы посоветовал какой-нибудь статический анализатор кода, к примеру, упомянутый во втором пункте `PVS-Studio`.

Comment: ReSharper не бесплатный...

Comment: @tCode есть студенческие/преподавательские лицензии и прочие способы получить его условно бесплатно.

Answer (score 2):

Выбирай из списка, пробуй и используй что понравится тебе:
[visual studio code refactoring](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_debugging/debugging/using-the-visual-studio-code-refactoring-tools.html)

Либо вот еще есть решения:
[Refactoring Essentials for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.RefactoringEssentialsforVisualStudio)

Либо:
[Resource Refactoring Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ResourceRefactoringTool)