# Бесплатный плагин для рефакторинга исходных текстов в Visual Studio 2012 для С/C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, плагин

Может, кто встречал решения для рефакторинга исходных текстов на С/C++ под  Visual Studio 2012?

Платные и условно бесплатные плагины, типы ReSharper не предлагайте, приобретать лицензию нет возможности :-(

Есть аналогичная тема [Плагин для рефакторинга для Visual Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1049258/%d0%9f%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-visual-studio), но меня интересует инструмент только для С/C++ кодов...

Comment: говорят, на одном трекере есть кряк для Visual Assist

Comment: Мы ведь, разработчики, а не пираты! ;)

Comment: @Инди Путный я новичок. А для чего это нужно? Что даёт этот инструмент в работе? Оптимизацию? Или чужой код под себя переделать?

Comment: Рефакторинг это в первую очередь улучшение качества кода. Я ищу инструментарий который позволяет изменять название объявленных переменных, объектов и и. д.. Оптимизация кода это тоже часть рефакторинга, но там больше приходиться пологаться на свои знания и умения работать с кодом, но когда нам необходимо изменить название объявления которое вызываеться и используеться в большой части кода, тут без вспомогательных инструментов очень тяжело.